# Laravel 5.4 : Many to many pivot table records

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have `User` and `Project` models.

The relationship is many to many.

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project')->withPivot('id');;
}
```

And in `Project` Model I have :

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('id');;
}
```

Now what I am doing :

`$projectsAsFreelancer = App\Project::where('assignedTo',$id)->get();`

What i want is to get the `username` from the `users` table of the user, Who have posted the project. The `Project` means `projects` table have the `forign_key`->`employeer_id`.

Currently `$project->pivot->username` gives me error.

`pivot` table name is `project_user`.

What i am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$project->pivot->username` requires the `username` field in your pivot table. `->withPivot('id');` is only required if you wish to get `id` column of the pivot table, `$project->pivot->id` wil give the value.

If you want to get username from users table you don't require pivot.

```
$projectsAsFreelancer = App\Project::where('assignedTo',$id)->get();
foreach($projectsAsFreelancer as $project)
{ 
    echo $project->name;
    foreach($project->users as $user)
     {
         echo $user->username;
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes i can do that but i need the project object too !

Comment: @Gamer `$projectsAsFreelancer` gives the collection of objects, and `$project` inside foreach gives you object.

Comment: So that object again needs a `foreach` means foreach in foreach ?

Comment: @Gamer yes. because there are many projects and a single project can have many users.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `get()`. It could not fetch the relations. You could use `first()` or `find()` (if you want to select with primary key)

```
$projectsAsFreelancer = App\Project::where('assignedTo',$id)->first();
foreach ($projectsAsFreelancer->users as $user) {
    //var_dump($user->username);
}
```

Comment: Yes i can do that but i need the project object too !